# Ggplot2: How to add 95% CI to percentage bar chart of factors?

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I am trying to add 95% confidence intervals to a frequency bar chart. I have tried extracting the CIs manually and inputting them into my data frame function but no luck. Is there any way of adding error bars so they don't look like this? I have a feeling its to do with the percentage function I have in the original plot code.

```
#Origin of the Value and Confidence Intervals
yesHousingonly<-cows$Housing.Status[cows$Result == "yes"]

prop.test(x = 7, n = 57, conf.level = 0.95)

data:  7 out of 57, null probability 0.5
X-squared = 30.947, df = 1, p-value = 2.651e-08
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.05490086 0.24290721
sample estimates:
       p 
0.122807 

prop.test(x = 3, n =57, conf.level = 0.95)

data:  3 out of 57, null probability 0.5
X-squared = 43.86, df = 1, p-value = 3.528e-11
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.0136917 0.1554719
sample estimates:
         p 
0.05263158 


#Data frame used to create ggplot
df5<-data.frame(yesHousingonly, upper=c(0.15, 0.24), lower=c(0.01, 0.05))

#GGplot of Percentage Prevalence of Cryptosporidium according to Housing Status
ggplotHousing<-ggplot(df5, aes(x = yesHousingonly, fill=yesHousingonly)) + geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + theme_bw()

#Error Bar attempt
ggplotHousing 
+ ylim(0,0.8) + geom_errorbar(data = df5, mapping = aes(ymin= upper, ymax = lower))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide us with the data contained in the ```yesHousingonly``` object? That would enable us to answer your question efficiently.

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/inserting-error-bars-on-a-percentage-graph/54337